# About android international language

Tags: android

Now, I'm doing a project, I would like to implement this software supports multiple languages
,My idea is to change the configuration file through xml,but I don's konw how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Localization for the same, simple example is given here just go through http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/android-application-localization-tutorial/ and can also refer this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: Vote up requires 15 reputation. I only have one ,so sorry.

Comment: but you can accept the answer by "right tick", if you find mine answer working

Comment: below the vote counter, leftside of my answer you will see the "right symbol"